# How to use the setTimeout(function () to delay the drop down menu in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, settimeout

How to use the setTimeout(function () to delay the drop down or  _mouseOverHandler the same way the _mouseOutHandler is delayed here. If you see the following menu there is a .250 second delay on close. I want the same delay on open or the drop down of menu.

Test Page:
http://terrillthompson.com/tests/menus/accessible-mega-menu/test.html

JS Code:
http://terrillthompson.com/tests/menus/accessible-mega-menu/js/jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js

Thanks in advance,
Rick

Comment: Please post the relevant code and markup here so that it is preserved for future SO'er's.

Comment: do you want to update the library or do from within your own js?

Comment: hi @jayaguilar I want to do it from my own js by modifying the jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried however the code is too long but here is the link to it http://terrillthompson.com/tests/menus/accessible-mega-menu/js/jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js

Cheers,
R

Comment: the way this library was created its a lot easier for you to just update the js itself, if you want me to tell you how do do it I'll submit it as an answer

Comment: Hey @jayaguilar yes if you can submit it as an answer that would be awesome! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ricardo79 2 things you need to for it to work the way you want it:

1.update _mouseOverHandler with:

`_mouseOverHandler = function (event) {
        var that= this;
         clearTimeout(this.mouseTimeoutID);
        $(event.target)
            .addClass(this.settings.hoverClass);
        that.mouseTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){
            _togglePanel.call(that, event);
        },250);
        if ($(event.target).is(':tabbable')) {
            $('html').on('keydown.accessible-megamenu', _keyDownHandler.bind(event.target));
        }
    };`.

2.add a clearTimeOut to _mouseOutHandler right after var that = this
`clearTimeout(this.mouseTimeoutID);`

here's a working sample http://jsfiddle.net/LfD9v/1/

Comment: Please attribute to the author of that code whenever you copy / paste code from an external resource.

Comment: @jayaguilar You Rock! Thank you so much! Works perfect.. I just have to do some css work and I'm rolling. Thanks again!

Comment: @RPM not sure what you mean by that but on the jsfiddle I left all of the authors credit, please let me know how to do this and I will gladly do so.

Comment: @Ricardo79 awesome if you dont mind can you accept the answer please.